# Pivot data from wide to long format in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have the following dataset that looks like this:

```
purchase_made | google.com | google.com/images | youtube.com | youtube.com/account
--------------|------------|-------------------|-------------|--------------------
yes           |   10000    |  2345             |  987        |  546
no            |   45000    |  1923             |  345        |  67
```

I am trying to use either `pivot_longer()` or `pivot()` to reshape the data into the following format:

```
url_visited        |     yes       | no
-------------------|---------------|---------------
google.com         |   10000       | 45000
google.com/images  |   2345        | 1923
youtube.com        |   987         | 345
youtube.com/account|   546         | 67
```

I have been using the following method but still quite stuck on it!

`df %>% pivot_longer(!purchase_made, names_to = 'url_link', values = count)`

But this does not reshape the data into the above long format.

any help is appreciated!

Comment: It is important your data is directly reproducible in R.

Comment: First get data in long format and then wide : `df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -purchase_made) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = purchase_made, values_from = value)`